# Should we migrate signal processing questions to dsp.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, topicality

In light of a [recent question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/5530/how-to-take-the-fft-of-an-undersampled-signal), I'm wondering to what extent we should accept digital signal processing questions and when we should migrate them to dsp.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 3):

For a while, I was in favor of letting signal processing questions go to see what was getting up votes and what was getting good answers, because I think we, as a community, should try to be inclusive.

I've updated the FAQ subsection "*There are certain subjects that will probably get better responses on our sister sites*" to include:

- **Image Processing**, ask on [DSP Stack Exchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) unless it relates to visualizing and processing scientific data, or unless it relates to implementing a specific algorithm for image processing, *as long as it is described in terms familiar to general computational scientists* (because most of us are unfamiliar with image processing jargon).

Looking at the image processing questions:

- [Optimal transport warping implementation in Matlab](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2162/optimal-transport-warping-implementation-in-matlab) is the highest voted, and describes implementing an algorithm for image processing in terms that many people in computational science would find accessble. [Second order directional derivative in image processing](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/second-order-directional-derivative-in-image-processing) does something similar. Both questions have accepted answers, and these seem like questions we as a community would want.
- [Trace An Isoline of an Expensive 2D Function](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1542/trace-an-isoline-of-an-expensive-2d-function) asks about how to find isolines and isosurfaces of a function, which is something someone might want to do in processing scientific data. (I actually tried to do something like this for a project in undergrad, and I did it badly.)
- The remaining questions don't have accepted answers, and don't have many up votes. A lot of them are heavy on jargon. These should probably be migrated over to DSP because our current user base for answering image processing questions is not very large. The answers posters get would likely be better if they asked them on [DSP Stack Exchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) instead of here.

I propose using the FAQ criterion to decide whether to migrate image processing questions. Is this criterion reasonable? If so, and a question does not meet the exclusions within it, then I believe it should be migrated in most cases. Is that stance also reasonable?